# HTML5 drag and drop upload - how to limit only local files

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I'm working on an HTML5 image drag-and-drop project and encounter a problem:

If a user drag an image that is already on the page, the onDragEnter/onDragOver events are still triggered.

Is there a way to trigger the event only if the file comes from the local computer (drag from desktop, folders, etc.), not from the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the [`draggable` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#the-draggable-attribute) on all page images to `false`?

Comment: Yes, I did set draggable="false" on all images. But the elements are still draggable. Here is the plugin I am using: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload